# Modal alert request for push notifications

Tags: objective-c, permissions, push-notification, modal-dialog

debuggers,

I have created an app that embeds push notifications.
For one or other reason the user does not get asked for permission on the first load.
In the past I have used push notification and everything seemed to work, the code for is pretty much "copy-pasted".

- I requested a certificate from a certificate authority (keychain)
- I enabled push notification and downloaded a new certificate
- Uploaded the certificate to apple and received a validated development and distribution certificate.
- I downloaded a new development + production provisioning profile.
- I signed the app with the provisioning profile.

When I open the provisioning profile in textedit I do see the following key:
aps-environment

I used this profile to sign the app and install it on to the device!

I have tried several methods like setting the time on my phone to days ahead, rebooting, re-installing.

I use urban airship as a push service!

Does anyone have any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: I faced with the same problem a week ago, but I don't bother about it, probably because I use development (not ad hoc) config. Maybe in release it will work fine..

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `[UAPush setDefaultPushEnabledValue:NO]` set by any chance?

By setting this value to NO UrbanAirship delay prompting users to enable push notifications until you are ready to ask. This gives you a chance to explain what they are used for instead of it popping up right when the app starts.

Then later you can enable them by calling
`UIRemoteNotificationType notificationTypes = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];`